# Cakephp change url?

Tags: cakephp

i want change my url in cake php  /eng/users/  to /users/; i mean when i entered this  /eng/users/ cakephp don't show me error like this

**Missing Controller
Error: EngController could not be found.
Error: Create the class "EngController" below in file: "app\Controller\EngController.php" **

both this /eng/users/ and /users/ become same ? any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Router.

Read this article: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

and especially for the cause of users ur you should add in your /app/Config/routes.php

```
Router::connect(
   '/eng/:controller/*', array('controller' => 'users')
);
```

the eng can be set to some prefix and so on.

Comment: thanks but i want for every controller and every view work well; with code above just work for users controller and show all view as index ?